# Not getting all Results from Partition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with my program creating partitions but not querying for each partition. The reason why i have to use partitions is because i am creating an Odata query string to my services api and if i query for more than 55 policies at one time the query string becomes too long and fails. I can see where my application divides the policies into separate partitions but thats as far as it goes. It queries for one and then does nothing for the other. Thanks for your help.

** EDIT once it partitions it gets here

```
  public void GetAllEligibleUnredeemedPoliciesForEachActiveAgentCodeForTheAgent()
    {
        AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode = new List<DtoApp2LeadPolicy>();
        foreach (var agentCode in _app2Agent.AllOfTheAgentCodesForTheAgent)
        {
            if (AgentPolicies != null)
                AgentPolicies = new List<DtoApp2LeadPolicy>();
            SetTheAgentCode(agentCode);
            SetAgentPolicyNumbersByAgentCode();
            SetAllPolicyNumbersByAgentsEligiblePolicies();
            SetAgentPoliciesFromAtlamServices();
            if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode.AddRange(AgentPolicies);
        }
    }
```

And the first partition gets skipped and not addedd.

```
public void PartitionThePolicyNumbers()
    {
        PartitionsOfPolicyNumbers = AllPolicyNumbers.Partition<string>( NumberOfPolicyNumberPartitions);
    }

    public void QueryTheWebServicesForEligiblePolicyDtosUsingEachPartition()
    {
        foreach
        (var partition in PartitionsOfPolicyNumbers)
        {
            SetThePolicyNumbersForThePartition(partition);
            SetAgentPolicyDtosFromWebServices();
            SetPoliciesForAgentView();
            AddEligiblePolicyDtosFromWebServicesCallToAllEligiblePoliciesForAgent();
        }
    }

    public void SetThePolicyNumbersForThePartition(IEnumerable<string> policyNumbers)
    {
        this.PolicyNumbers = policyNumbers;
    }

    public void AddEligiblePolicyDtosFromWebServicesCallToAllEligiblePoliciesForAgent()
    {
        if (AllEligiblePoliciesForAgentView == null) AllEligiblePoliciesForAgentView = new List<DtoApp2LeadPolicy>();
        foreach (var policyDto in _app2Lead.AgentPolicies)
        {
            AllEligiblePoliciesForAgentView.Add(policyDto);
        }
    }

    public void SetNumberOfPartitionsForPolicyNumbers()
    {
        NumberOfPolicyNumberPartitions = CalculateNumberOfPolicyNumberPartitions();
    }

    public int CalculateNumberOfPolicyNumberPartitions()
    {
        var numberOfPolicyNumbers = AllPolicyNumbers.Count();
        if (numberOfPolicyNumbers < 55) return 1;
        return (numberOfPolicyNumbers / 55) + 1; 
    }
```

Comment: Does it properly partition the policy numbers? Does it only query for one policy number although there is more than one policy number?

Comment: It does properly partition the policies. Let me add an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create method to add policies outside of Agentpoliciesforeach code method

```
    public void AddAgentPolicies()
    {
        if (AgentPolicies != null) AgentPoliciesForEachAgentCode.AddRange(AgentPolicies);
    }
```